# Список кнопок WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Подскажите, как можно получить все кнопки из формы wpf и загнать их в массив?

Comment: А зачем вам? Вам не должно быть это нужно.

Answer (score 2):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
...
public static List<T> GetVisualChilds<T>(DependencyObject parent) where T : DependencyObject
{
  List<T> childs = new List<T>();
  int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
  for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
  {
    DependencyObject v = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
    if (v is T)
      childs.Add(v as T);
    childs.AddRange(GetVisualChilds<T>(v));
  }
  return childs;
}
...
//Естественно this - это Ваша форма или контрол для поиска
List<Button> allButtons = GetVisualChilds<Button>(this.Content as DependencyObject);
```

Comment: Прикрутил... Почему-то в списке 0 элементов. Форму передал...

Comment: Кнопки добавлены как `<button/>`? Вы точно выполняете код после добавления кнопок на форму?

Comment: <Button x:Name="Add_SettingsPC" Content="Add" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="147,67,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Add_SettingsPC_Click"/>

Код выполняю после загрузки формы

Comment: Да, согласен, необходим  `GetVisualChilds<Button>(this.Content as DependencyObject)`